# Stop big view (expansion) of notification in tray for Google FCM in React-Native implementation (react-native-firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm using [Firebase Messaging (FCM)](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/tree/master/packages/messaging) in a React-Native setting.

When the notification is at the top on the tray, it expands by default (Big View). Also, it expands when user tries to expand it.
However, there is no way mentioned in the documentation to turn off the expansion / big view. Not even for those notifications which aren't at the top of the tray.

The problem faced by me is the use of image in notification, which is square in shape (cannot use rectangular / landscape images), and gets cropped and looks really awkward.

I may be wrong, but if I've missed some parameter / flag that `react-native-firebase` provides to be used that can turn off big view, or set bigText to be null, or some other solution so that expansion of notification-item cannot happen, at least when its not on top of the tray.